# Mess class design

Tags: oop, design-patterns

I have a class design that looks like this one:

[image]

When Main receives an item, properties of other items can change based on some rules. For example, if Item1 has a red color, item2.level must be 3. Sometimes a value can change properties of multiple items. Implementing all rules in Main class is possible but it's a mess code.

So, I have implemented the Aggregate class that include all items. When Main.setItem(item1) is executed, I update Aggregate with Aggregate.setItem1 and run Rules.updateAggregate that updates items of Aggregate according to all rules.

It works, but Rules class is very inefficient. Because it doesn't know which item has updated, it apply all rules all times. Also, updateAggregate method is very large and difficult to test.

Is there any better design?

Comment: This question is too broad. There are potentially an infinite number of better designs, depending on the definition of _better_. What design properties are you looking to achieve?

Comment: "*Implementing all rules in Main class is possible but it's a mess code.*" - why exactly do you think that? From what I can see, it's `Main`'s responsibility as it is the class with the three `setItem` methods. Why do you think the rules become less of a mess to implement in a different class, e.g. `Rules` or `Aggregate`? Does `Main` actually have some other responsibilities besides maintaining the aggregate and its three items?

Comment: Yes, Bergi, Main have other responsabilities. The diagram is only a simplification. Implementing all rules in Main class adds toomuch complexity.

Comment: I didn't understand the logic. Can you clarify following? Are "Items" interested updated of other items? For example, Item3 is updated but also Item1 is interested in the changes because it can have a rule why it should change its values?

Comment: @T.Nylund, yes that's right. But the rules for change not depend on only one property. For example, quantity property of item3 depends on duration property of item2 and color property of item1. When color item1 is changed, quantity item3 must change according to new color item1 value and current duration item2 value.

Comment: Thanks. This helped a little bit. And how about the following question, can you clarify, if I am on the right track. Are Rules related to Items? So there is a set of rules how Item should behave when some values are changed? So basically all logic how every Item objects are updated is inside Rules? And there are no rules inside Item classes? The last question is, how many different Item classes you have or how often those are changed?

Comment: @T.Nylund Rules are only related to property items. For example, "item3.quantity = (item1.color = 'red') ? 3 : 2 * item2.duration". Items haven't any more logic than that. Rules could be in Item classes, but then I would need a reference to all other Items to apply them. Item classes are very different, I haven't found any way to extend from a common interface. Some properties like cost are in all Items, but the majority are different. Items only change when there are some rule to apply.

Comment: "Because it doesn't know which item has updated, it apply all rules all times.". What about something as simple as `updateAggregate(Aggregate aggregate, Item itemSet)`? By the way, managing dependencies will most likely be very difficult if every rules aren't made first-class citizens. You could easily miss cyclic dependencies, etc.

Comment: Ok. I understand your problem now. I made an example from your code structure. https://gist.github.com/nyluntu/c0c6726f2b6e6796004dee9d7d876f75 The example is my starting point. Probably it is similar than you code but much more simplified. Using C# as a language. I am going to make one example that could work and hope it gives you more ideas.

Comment: @T.Nylund Thanks, that's more or less my code. In Main class I have setItem methods implemented like this: setItem1 (item1) { aggregate.setItem1(item1); rules.updateAggregate(aggregate); }

Comment: Yep. My second version was just like that. I found this problem very interesting and have a question about the rules. I was trying to implement this with observer pattern so when Item1 changes, for example, Item3 will react to that. Can you explain, is there any priority between the different Item -classes? For example, should Item1 be checked first, then Item2, then Item3 etc.? That was a possible case that I realized to be important. Or can Item3.quantity change cause an effect on Item1-values? This is important because it can easily cause circular dependencies to rules.

Comment: Rules guarantee that there isn't circular dependencies and no priorities. But one item change can trigger another change. For example, Item3.quantity modification cause item1.cost modification and this one can trigger other Item2 change.

Comment: I added my own answer and it is probably the best I can write with the given information. But anyway check if it useful or not. There are many other ways to do similar logic but I hope you get some new ideas while trying the example. Normally, there are some business rules that should be implemented with TDD and it could reveal problems in the design.

Answer (score 1):

To reduce the coupling you could use a design based on events.
`Main` and `Item` classes should be publishers of events and `Item` classes should be also subscribers of event types as they want to react to events.
You should define some event types. For example :

- event type : "new Item with ..."
- event type : "Item 1 changed the foo property"

and so for...

Comment: The problem with events is that some rules depends on multiple Item values. If Item1 receives "item2 property change", maybe need an Item3 property to apply the rule.

Comment: If Item1 also needs Item3 to apply the rule, create an event type that transmit the two information and makes Item1 registers to. Even types can be what you need.

Answer (score 1):

According to question and comments, here is one example of a design that could work. [Gist link to the example code](https://gist.github.com/nyluntu/d2184554d740a404cf718770ad81cf8a)

The example is made using C# but should not have any problems to implement other languages. (Could be easier with dynamic languages)

The design probably doesn’t fit directly to your use case but here are a few points what I try to demonstrate with it and maybe you can find better ideas with this way.

I made a few iterations and this was the first version that I could work on a similar use case without any third party libraries.

## Main points of design

- In the example, I try to keep Item -classes very clean from rules.
- Rules -class is disappeared because, in the example, rules are in Aggregate class. However, I don’t see any problem to implement the same rules in separated Rules class, if needed. I don’t know exactly how complex your rules are and tried to keep the example simple.
- The aggregate has methods to raise “notification” about Item changes.
- I didn’t test my example but the implementation should be easier to test. For example, you should be put Items on specific state and try how rule behavior works. This can be validated to use unit tests but I didn't have any real use cases.
- I tried to kept classes decoupled as possible.

## Downsides

- Depending on your needs, classes can be too coupled. Specially Aggregate can contain a lot of code so the more decoupled solution should be possible.
- Implementation can be varied by programming languages and not always so clean. Originally, I used a similar pattern with event sourcing and modified to this example.
- If a number of Items are huge, then the design is not very flexible.

## How to improve

As said in comments and other answers, event-based implementation is probably what you want. I used Observer pattern as a starting point but it was going towards event-based implementation.

You should also look at some event-driven libraries that can have a good example of how to implement an application that reacts to changes. Also, those libraries usually help to wire up objects and give more decoupled implementation. Of course, then you are coupled with those libraries but probably not a bad case. No need to reinvent this mechanism anyway.

Check following links that can help with new ideas. [Observer vs pub-sub pattern](https://hackernoon.com/observer-vs-pub-sub-pattern-50d3b27f838c)

Comment: I have been studing your code and I appreciate your effort. I think event design is a bit complex for the problem I want to solve. Anyway I will see if I can take some idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I completelly agree with @davidxxx that events based design is better approach in your case. You can have a look at the observer design pattern. In case your business logic is so complex that you are not able to provide reqired parameters , you can always inject the whole list/tree/whatever of items and perform find operations on it.